JavaScript from Django Base Not Working On Startup
I am attempting to get a customer logo to load when a user signs into my app. The JS function is not firing and I do not see any information in the logs
To do that I am using the views function below to generate the logo url:
Views:
def view_company_logo(request):

print("GETTING LOGO")

client = Client.objects.get(user=request.user)
logo = ""


try:
        logo = client.customer.first().logo.url + settings.MEDIA_URL
        print("GOT LOGO")

    except Exception as e:
        logo = ""
        print(e)
        print(f'ERROR FOR LOGO {e}')
    finally:
        return JsonResponse({"logo": logo}, safe=False)

The function is attached the url below:
url(r"^get/company_logo/$", views.view_company_logo),

This is called in the base.html file in order to show the
  $(document).ready(function () {
  function get_company_logo() {
    log('TEST');

    $.ajax({
      url: '/get/company_logo/',
      method: 'GET',
      success: function (data) {
        return create_image(data['logo'])





      },
      error: function () {
        console.log('HERE IS THE ERROR!!!')
        log('HERE IS THE ERROR!!!')
      },
    
    })
  }

  function create_image(logo) {
    document.getElementById("logo").src = logo;

  }


  get_company_logo()

Which connects to the source of this image that gets generated when the pages loads:
      <img class="img-square center" id="logo" alt="logo" style="opacity: 1" height="45" width="125">

Could someone tell me why the image is not loading? It seems like the function is never called and I am not sure why.

Your "return" statement returns a value from the success function.  It doesn't return a value from the get_company_logo function.  That returns nothing.

@TimRoberts I updated the function but, that did not work. Could you tell me if it is written incorrectly?

If you log the data in the callback, is the URL correct?  Do see log messages from your django function?

No I do not see anything. @TimRoberts

You might show how you do the routing in Django.

I am routing via url. I added that information to the post. Is there something else you are asking about? @TimRoberts

I'm TRYING to guide you toward debugging this.  Is your request being made?  Is it getting into your django code at all?  Is the function being called?  Do you have a routing error?  Before you can FIX it, you need to know where it's going awry.  For now, you're just guessing.

@TimRoberts I do not believe the function is being called and I do not understand where the error is. That is the nature of the question. It seems like the JS function is not being called inside the $document loading feature.

I do not believe the function is being called -- well, you need to come up with a YES or NO answer.  That's what console.log is good for.  Do you see "TEST" in the console log?

I do not see any information in the console. The function is not being called. That was mentioned in the post at the bottom. Please read all the way through. @TimRoberts –

You have multiple problems in your Javascript.  The only thing that needs to be in the "ready" function is the call to get_company_logo.  The other functions can be defined directly.
This works for me:
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js">
</script>
<script>
function get_company_logo() {
    console.log('TEST');

    $.ajax({
      url: '/get/company_logo/',
      method: 'GET',
      success: function (data) {
        return create_image(data['logo'])
      },
      error: function () {
        console.log('HERE IS THE ERROR!!!')
        log('HERE IS THE ERROR!!!')
      },
    
    })
}

function create_image(logo) {
  document.getElementById("logo").src = logo;
}

$(document).ready(get_company_logo);

</script>

<img class="img-square center" id="logo" alt="logo" style="opacity: 1" height="45" width="125">


You pass the media URL value. While you need to add media_root to download the photo:
    logo = client.customer.first().logo.url
    print("GOT LOGO")
    return JsonResponse({"logo": logo + settings.MEDIA_URL}, safe=False)

In addition, it is better to clean your code:
try:
    logo = client.customer.first().logo.url + settings.MEDIA_URL
    print("GOT LOGO")

except Exception as e:
    logo = ""
    print(e)
    print(f'ERROR FOR LOGO {e}')
finally:
    return JsonResponse({"logo": logo}, safe=False)


This did not work. I think the JS function isnt firing. Could you let me know what could I be doing wrong there?
